# reading sequential numerical registry keys in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to read from 
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\BOSCH\RBcm\PMI\Client\Applications\
and place just the values of each key into an array. The issue that I am having is that there are 55 keys, whose Names are 0 though 54 (not a hand full of keys with names like DisplayName, Publisher, etc.)

0       REG_SZ    XXX, 
1       REG_SZ    YYY, 
3       REG_SZ    ZZZ, 
..
54      REG_SZ    ABC

How can I do this efficiently? I appreciate the help.

Since I am very new to Powershell, I need details on how I would complete expression to store only the data values in array $Programs
`enter code here`

Get-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\BOSCH\RBcm\PMI\Client\Applications"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access it with `PSObject` *hidden* properties.

```
$Programs[0].PSObject.Properties.Name
```

You can also drill down these objects and explore for more data available and build desired output. Like so:

```
foreach ($Program in $Programs){
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    foreach ($property in $Program.PSObject.Properties){
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $property.Name -Value $property.Value
    }
    $obj
}
```

Comment: I added some detail to my original post

Comment: @Stett, I have updated my answer. Hope you get the point now.